# How to avoid sending the form multiple times

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, jquery-dialog

I have a form in a jquery dialog, which has no submit button. Instead, it is submitted by clicking on OK dialog button.

So when click OK, this happens:

```
var data = $('#form').serialize();
$.post('page.php',data)
  .success( function(result) {

  // result might be description of an error or other problem, then I display error
  ...
  // or ok, then I hide form and change OK button, so now it closes the dialog
  ...
  myDialog.dialog( "option", "buttons", [{ text: ok, click: function() { $(this).dialog("close"); } }] );    

 });
```

It works fine. Data of the form are rows, they get afterwards displayed in the table at the page. But I got reported several times, that user submitted N rows and got 3xN new rows. So it looks like she managed to accidentaly send the form 3 times, before the OK click function changed.

I don't see how this might happen. I have tried a lot to doubleclick or tripleclick the OK button, and the result was

- the data was send once
- the form wasn't hidden
- even though the form wasn't hidden, after clicking OK the dialog closed and nothing was send again

So I need your advice. What can I do to prevent her from sending the same form multiple times again?

Comment: So your problem isn't with the accidental multiple clicking? Because if I understand you correctly, you weren't able to reproduce the same bug but multiple clicking, right?

Comment: I wasn't able to reproduce it. That is why I don't get how she does it, but this is not the first time complaint and I can see in the system she really has some triple rows.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest that you unbind the click event listener from your button after you clicked it once. This may be just a simple solution but I think it will work fine.

```
$('#submitButton').click(function(){

    $(this).unbind('click');

    var data = $('#form').serialize();

    $.post('page.php',data).success( function(result) {
        // result might be description of an error or other problem, then I display error
        ...
        // or ok, then I hide form and change OK button, so now it closes the dialog
        ...
        myDialog.dialog( "option", "buttons", [{ text: ok, click: function() {
        $(this).dialog("close"); } }] );    
    });
});
```

**EDIT**

If you want to rebind the click function if the result of the form is invalid:

```
$('#submitButton').click(function(){
    submitForm();
});

function submitForm();    
    $('#submitButton').unbind('click');

    var data = $('#form').serialize();

    $.post('page.php',data).success( function(result) {
        // result might be description of an error or other problem, then I display error

        // if result invalid rebind the click event
        if(resultInvalid){
            $('#submitButton').click(function(){
                submitForm();
            });
        }
        // or ok, then I hide form and change OK button, so now it closes the dialog
        ...
        myDialog.dialog( "option", "buttons", [{ text: ok, click: function() {
        $(this).dialog("close"); } }] );    
    });
}
```

Comment: Ok, I will try this. I hope the click() function will still run to the end. In addition I have to bind it again in the case the result is not ok, because this may mean just some validation warning.

Comment: thank you. so I will let it this way in the hope this fixes the bug.

Answer (score 1):

you can use one() instead.

```
$("#submitButton").one("click", function() {
  //ajax code here
});
```